# Ruby on Rails, Act-as-Taggable-On and Ancestry (Categories). How to deal with?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, acts-as-taggable-on, ancestry

I have a model "Post" that belongs_to "Category" model.

Category model "has_ancestry" because of nested system.

I need to show on index page of posts, the posts with params:

Category=First&Tag=AnyTag(or many more tags)

How to accomplish this?

Obviously when I'm on the posts list and I view the list of tags for a single post and I click on tag, I have to "link_to" page of that Category with that tag in params[:tag]. If I'm not in explicit category => Post.all)

I'm using for tags Acts-As-Taggable-On.

How to?

Comment: When user selects on each tag you need to add it to input field value(array). That way you could pass multiple tags in a URL.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question...